# Build general form of an infinite sequence

Tags: series-expansion, sequence

Please, I would like to build the general form of an infinite number sequence

$$\dfrac{8}{35}, \dfrac{5}{21} ,\dfrac{8}{33} ,\dfrac{35}{143},\dfrac{16}{65} ,\dfrac{21}{85} 
    ,\dfrac{80}{323},\dfrac{33}{133},\dfrac{40}{161}, \cdots$$

as the form $\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}$. For example, I should get

$\dfrac{8}{35}$ for $n =1$ or $n =2$ (or $n =3$), $\dfrac{5}{21}$ for $n =2$, ....

I already asked this question on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3595329/how-to-find-general-form-of-sequence)
but without success.
I thought Mathematica could find this general form!

Somone has an idea please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
FindSequenceFunction[{8/35, 5/21, 8/33, 35/143, 16/65, 21/85, 
                      80/323, 33/133, 40/161}, n] // FullSimplify

(*    ((1 + n) (3 + n))/((3 + 2 n) (5 + 2 n))    *)
```

Comment: Great this Mathematica. Thank you @Roman, I'm extremely grateful.

Answer (score 5):

Using **[SequenceToSum](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SequenceToSum?i=SequenceToSum&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch)**:

```
 ResourceFunction["SequenceToSum"] [{8/35, 5/21, 8/33, 35/143, 16/65, 21/85, 80/323, 33/133,40/161, \[Ellipsis]}, n]

 (*Inactive[Sum][(3 + 4 n + n^2)/(15 + 16 n + 4 n^2), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]*)
```

$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{n^2+4 n+3}{4 n^2+16 n+15}$$

Comment: This is the sum of the sequence. Since the sequence does not converge to zero (the sequence goes to `1/4`), the sum diverges.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mariusz Iwaniuk. I'm extremely grateful. But not the sum of termes, just the terms that I'm looking for.

Comment: @BobHanlon a bit of [zeta function regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization) can be used to make this sum converge: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)(n+3)}{(2n+3)(2n+5)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(n+1)(n+3)}{(2n+3)(2n+5)}-\frac14\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{s\to0}\frac{n^s}{4}=-\frac{3}{40}+\frac14\lim_{s\to0}\zeta(-s)=-\frac{3}{40}-\frac18=-\frac15$. If you don't believe it, start reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_⋯).